# Integrating Okta with ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: asp.net, okta

I am trying to connect Okta to ASP.NET web forms application and was successful in doing so but I am unable to fetch user ID i.e. Email ID from the okta.

I followed the following link for integrating okta with ASP.NET - https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/29/secure-webforms-with-openidconnect-okta

I was able to fetch user name using -
`<%= ((Page.User.Identity.Name).ToString()) %>`

Please help me to fetch email id from okta.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Profile Editor on OKTA admin website and update application's Profile Mapping to map user.login -> name.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question recently: [okta-asp-net-how-do-i-get-the-user-name-log-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443361/okta-asp-net-how-do-i-get-the-user-name-log-in-id-unique-identifier-of-t/57446993#57446993)

I resolved using the code below:

```
var userId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username");
```

Comment: Richard do u know how to enable user registeration in OKTA from asp.net web Forms if the page visitor dont have login credentials(new user) ?

Comment: What do you mean by user registration?  You mean self registration?

Comment: yes! the user must be able to register himself.