# okta - asp.net - How do I get the User Name / Log In Id / Unique Identifier of the current user sign in? - Standard Way?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, okta

Using okta, how do I get the User Name / Log In Id / Unique Identifier of the current user signed in?

I am currently working on an ASP.Net Web Forms App.   After the user successfully signs in, I can get the name of the user with the code below.

```
var name = User.Identity.Name;
```

However, I want the Log In Id / Unique Identifier of the User.  Looking at the Profile form on the okta web site, it looks like okta calls that field User Name.

After doing some research, I did write up some code that gets what I want using the ClaimsPrincipal class and claimType == "preferred_username".  But the code seems like a hack to me. Looking for the Standard Way to get this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. You do have to locate a claim based on its "type" but it's simple enough:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
var userId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("preferred_username");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I added:

```
var userId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username");
```